# Manipular diretamente variaveis $_GET e $_POST

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma aplicação que trabalhará com uma quantidade grande de dados a serem manipulados e armazenados em um banco de dados, então é indicado armazenar os valores presentes em variáveis `$_GET` e `$_POST` em variáveis intermediarias (o que acarretaria em duplicação de memória gasta) ou alterar diretamente `$_GET` e `$_POST`?

Comment: A memória ou processamento supostamente desperdiçado é ínfimo para você se preocupar. Se bem me lembro, oq eu você deve evitar é utilizar aqueles "famosos" ternários quando a variável por eles testadas contiver bastante informação. Fora isso, concentre-se em evitar outras armadilhas glutonas ao longo da Aplicação e você estará coberto.

Comment: OK, em um outro cenário, onde existe "milhoes" de envios ao banco, poderia-se manipular diretamente as superglobais a fim de economizar memoria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há nada que impeça você de manipular esta variável. Desconheço qualquer coisa que indique que vá criar algum problema. Não há nada na documentação que diga que você deva evitar. Mas algumas ponderações devem ser observadas.

- O PHP não é a melhor linguagem para trabalhar com grandes volumes de dados de uma só vez. Muito menos é a linguagem para se pensar quando espera-se grande otimização de uso de recursos. Se realmente precisa disto, escolha a ferramenta certa.
- Com `$_GET` você não pode manipular milhões de dados. Nunca virá sequer milhares se o protocolo for respeitado.
- Se você vai receber milhões de campos em uma só requisição você está fazendo algo muito errado, tem tantos outros problemas que podem ocorrer, tanta coisa para se preocupar que este problema chega ser quase irrelevante.
- PHP não mantém dados na memória que não mais são referenciados. Pelo menos ele diz que não mantém. Então não sei se teria essa duplicação que você espera.
- Precisa ver se realmente precisa duplicar. Estou entendendo que você quer escrever neste *array*. Mas quase sempre o que as pessoas querem é apenas ler o conteúdo dele e usar em algum lugar. Não há problema algum nisto. Nada. Noto que alguns programadores acham que é preciso jogar um campo vindo pelo `$_POST` em uma variável local e depois usar a variável. Isto realmente é desperdício provavelmente causado pela insistência das pessoas seguirem receita de bolo ao invés de aprenderem desenvolver software.
- Fora isto, é uma otimização completamente desnecessária.
- Se ainda insistir nisto, faça um teste de *stress* e chegue a alguma conclusão para o seu caso real. Ninguém poderá te dar informação melhor que esta.

A exceção seria se estiver utilizando *threads*, o que duvido que seja o caso. Pela natureza dos programas PHP raramente elas beneficiam um programa. Novamente, se alguém acha que precisa de *thread* para obter melhor performance ela provavelmente optará por outra linguagem.

Comment: ,@bigown, em: Com $_GET você não pode manipular milhões de dados, me expressei mal, seria milhares de pessoas enviando dados (cadastro pessoal), para um servidor e não uma unica pessoa enviando milhares de dados

Comment: As execuções são efêmeras e a estrutura geral para manipular o *script* ocupa tanto espaço que é pouco provável que este uso vá fazer alguma diferença fundamental. Se fizer, PHP não é a linguagem para você usar.

Comment: Depende. Se o script tiver uma lógica complexa a qual não foi otimizada corretamente onde possível, a execução vai ser lenta e a concorrência (que é o que preocupa o OP) pode matar a Aplicação. Infelizmente os superglobais **não são** somente leitura, então você pode fazer o que quiser com eles. Mas é questão de bom senso.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto "não foi otimizada corretamente" este é o ponto, ficar reaproveitando variável não é otimização correta. Nem eu nem o AP falamos em concorrência em nenhum momento. Mas se concorrência for o problema, a solução também é outra.

Comment: Então você precisa entender melhor o que é concorrência.